# Hash.includes? gives weird result in crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to write the Crystal equivalent of this Python code:

```
test_hash = {}
test_hash[1] = 2
print(1 in test_hash)
```

This prints True, because 1 is one of the keys of the dict.

Here's the Crystal code that I've tried:

```
# Create new Hash
test_hash = Hash(Int32, Int32).new
# Map 1 to 2
test_hash[1] = 2
# Check if the Hash includes 1
pp! test_hash.includes?(1)
```

But `includes?` returns false here. Why? What's the correct equivalent of my Python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `has_key?` instead. `has_key?` asks if the Hash has that key.

However, `includes?` checks if a certain key/value pair is in the hash table. If you supply just the key, it will always return false.

Example:

```
# Create new Hash
test_hash = Hash(Int32, Int32).new
# Map 1 to 2
test_hash[1] = 2
# Check if the Hash includes 1
pp! test_hash.has_key?(1)
# Check if the Hash includes 1 => 2
pp! test_hash.includes?({1, 2})


# Pointless, do not use
pp! test_hash.includes?(1)
```

Comment: How would you use `includes?` with the key/value pair both there?  Something doesn't feel quite right here...

Comment: @rogerdpack: "How would you use `includes?`" is beside the point. `includes?({K, V})` is the consequence of `Hash` being `Enumerable<{K, V}>`. Hash being Enumerable is a very cool thing, and even if I never use `Hash#includes?` I might use `Hash#each`, `Hash#group_by` or any of the other great tools there.